# xparse's \DeclareDocumentEnvironment gives error on already-defined environment

Tags: macros, subcaption, xparse

I'm trying to redefine an existing environment `subfigure` defined by the `subcaption` package. To do this, I'm using `xparse`'s `DeclareDocumentEnvironment` since that's suppose to declare a new environment no matter if it already exists or not. But for some reason I still get a compilation warning that the `\subfigure` command already exists.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{subfigure}{m}{%
  % Do nothing
}{%
  \subcaption{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{The caption}
    The figure
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Why doesn't this work as intended?

A workaround is of course to simply use another name for my custom environment, but I'm curious why this doesn't work as I want it to.

Comment: The error comes from `subcaption` that wants to define `subfigure` when `\AtBeginDocument`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `subcaption` package delays the definition of `subfigure` and `subtable` when executing the `\AtBeginDocument` hook. So the error is because `\newenvironment{subfigure}` wants to define an already existing environment. Indeed, you get exactly the same error if you use `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.

If you do

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareDocumentEnvironment{subfigure}{m}{%
    % Do nothing
  }{%
    \subcaption{#1}%
  }%
}
```

you get no error.

Comment: Hm. Any idea why `subcaption` does that? Why not define the environments directly as `subcaption.sty` is being read?

Comment: Interestingly, `subcaption.sty` doesn't define a `subfigure` environment – at least none that I can see…

Comment: @gablin The package wants to make several checks, so it must ensure as hard as it can that all packages are already loaded when it does them.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, it does `\newenvironment{sub#1}{...}{...}` for `#1` equal to the already defined and registered float types.

Comment: I saw that and thought the same, but I couldn't for the life of me find the origin of that. Usings emacs' up-list function stopped well before I saw any indication of a macro definition. Am I making any sense? **Edit:** Unless that's what `\caption@For` does, akin to expl3's map-inline functions?